# How to use ."in" filter in Supabase URL

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to use ".in" filter of Supabase using its URL. However I can't query for more than 1 filter.

Working url

`https://DATABASE_URL/rest/v1/patients?payer=in.(TERM1)`

Here I get all the rows where payer is `TERM1`. However, when I try the following

`https://DATABASE_URL/rest/v1/patients?payer=in.(TERM1, TERM2)`

I only get all the rows where payer is `TERM1`.
Expected output would be to get all the rows where payer is either `TERM1` or `TERM2`

Payer column is of type text.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to remove the space between TERM1 and TERM2 and try it again? Like this:

https://DATABASE_URL/rest/v1/patients?payer=in.(TERM1,TERM2)

Comment: Facinating how it was such a small issue. Thanks Bo!